# How to view "Old" timeline format

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, qtwebkit

I was hoping to be able to load a timeline I saved (Embedded QTWebkit) using the Chrome web tools however on trying to load it I get the error "Old Timeline format is not supported." Does anybody know of a tool I can use to display the "Old" format or a way I can convert the data?

Comment: I've been advised to try installing an old version of Chromium that supports the old format....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to convert the old format into the new one, but you can try loading data on [webpagetest.org timeline](http://www.webpagetest.org/chrome/timeline.php)